# How to transpose data in Table to a query in Access 2007

Tags: database

I have a table called Charges where a user enters data in the following fields

```
CHARGEID|FINANCIAL_YEAR|GABBAGE_FEE|ADVERT_FEE
```

I would like to have a transposed view of the above fields to appear in one column.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
qry_PoNumbering.[ID],
qry_PoNumbering.[From],
qry_PoNumbering.[PO Date],
qry_PoNumbering.[PO NUMBER],
qry_PoNumbering.[PO Detailas],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product1],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 1],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT1],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE1],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 1],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE1],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE1],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product2],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT2],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 2],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE2],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 2],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE2],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE2],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product3],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT3],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 3],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE3],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 3],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE3],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE3],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product4],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT4],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 4],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE4],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 4],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE4],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE4],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product5],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT5],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 5],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE5],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 5],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE5],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE5],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product6],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT6],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 6],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE6],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 6],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE6],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE6],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product7],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT7],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 7],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE7],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 7],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE7],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE7],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product8],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT8],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 8],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE8],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 8],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE8],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE8],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product9],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT9],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 9],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE9],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 9],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE9],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE9],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product10],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT10],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 10],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE10],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 10],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE10],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE10],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product11],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT11],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 11],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE11],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 11],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE11],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE11],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product12],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT12],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 12],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE12],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 12],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE12],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE12],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product13],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT13],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 13],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE13],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 13],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE13],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE13],
qry_PoNumbering.[SUBTOTAL],
qry_PoNumbering.[VAT],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL],
qry_PoNumbering.[Supplier Name],
qry_PoNumbering.[Invoice #],
qry_PoNumbering.[Invoice Date],
qry_PoNumbering.[EXECUTED]
FROM qry_PoNumbering
;
the sequence to have is: product unit qty unit price discount final price total
(
   UNIT price-UNIT price*DISCOUNT
)
price(qty * final price) invoice# invoice DATE
SELECT
qry_PoNumbering.[ID],
qry_PoNumbering.[From],
qry_PoNumbering.[PO Date],
qry_PoNumbering.[PO NUMBER],
qry_PoNumbering.[PO Detailas],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product1],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 1],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT1],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE1],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 1],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE1],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE1],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product2],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT2],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 2],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE2],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 2],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE2],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE2],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product3],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT3],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 3],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE3],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 3],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE3],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE3],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product4],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT4],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 4],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE4],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 4],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE4],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE4],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product5],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT5],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 5],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE5],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 5],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE5],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE5],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product6],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT6],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 6],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE6],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 6],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE6],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE6],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product7],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT7],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 7],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE7],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 7],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE7],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE7],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product8],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT8],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 8],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE8],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 8],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE8],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE8],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product9],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT9],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 9],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE9],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 9],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE9],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE9],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product10],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT10],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 10],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE10],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 10],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE10],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE10],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product11],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT11],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 11],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE11],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 11],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE11],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE11],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product12],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT12],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 12],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE12],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 12],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE12],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE12],
qry_PoNumbering.[Product13],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT13],
qry_PoNumbering.[QTY 13],
qry_PoNumbering.[UNIT PRICE13],
qry_PoNumbering.[DIC 13],
qry_PoNumbering.[FINAL PRICE13],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL PRICE13],
qry_PoNumbering.[SUBTOTAL],
qry_PoNumbering.[VAT],
qry_PoNumbering.[TOTAL],
qry_PoNumbering.[Supplier Name],
qry_PoNumbering.[Invoice #],
qry_PoNumbering.[Invoice Date],
qry_PoNumbering.[EXECUTED]
FROM qry_PoNumbering
;the sequence to have is: product unit qty unit price discount final price total
(
   UNIT price-UNIT price*DISCOUNT
)
price(qty * final price) invoice# invoice DATE
```